# While loop not terminating even after the 'return'

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop

I am using the while loop to iterate through an array and trying to terminate the loop using the return (I tried foreach before which doesn't terminate for return but the while loop should terminate with the use of return).

Can someone help me why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
req.on("data", async data => {
    let fetchedData = JSON.parse(data.toString())
    let index=0
    while(index<fetchedData.length) {
      const invoice = fetchedData[index]
    // fetchedData.forEach((invoice, index) => {
      console.log('index',index)
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(
          `SELECT * FROM payments WHERE invoice_id = '${invoice.id}' and status = 1`,
          (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              resolve()
              return res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: "something went wrong!",
              })
            } else {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                resolve()
                console.log('returned')
                return res.json({
                  status: "error",
                  message: `Payment is already done for invoice number ${invoice.invoiceNumber} ! Please delete the payment first.`,
                })
              } else if (index == fetchedData.length - 1) {
                for(let i =0; i<fetchedData.length; i++){
                  db.query(`UPDATE invoices SET status = 0 WHERE id = '${fetchedData[i].id}'`, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                      resolve()
                      return res.json({
                        status: "error",
                        message: "something went wrong!",
                      })
                    } else{
                      deletedInvoices.push(fetchedData[i].id)
                      if(i == fetchedData.length - 1){
                        console.log('deleted')
                        return res.json({
                          status: "success",
                          message: "invoice deleted",
                          deletedInvoices: deletedInvoices
                        })
                      }
                      resolve()
                    }
                  })
                }
              }
            }
          }
        )
      })
      index++;
    }
  })
```

output:
for an array with the length of 2:

> index 0

> returned

> index 1

> returned

(it also throws an error because it is sending a response two times!

Comment: There’s no `return` in the loop. There’s a `return` in a callback function to an async function, which triggers way after the loop is already done.

Comment: Since you've wrapped this in a Promise you can in theory call reject. You'll still be inside the while loop though. I'd untangle this callback hell and use await for each query instead of callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statements are not part of the `while` loop that is in the `req.on` callback, but are part of `dq.query` callback functions. So they don't relate to the loop.

An approach is to *promisify* the `db.query` function. Check the documentation of your database API, as there might already be a promise-returning alternative for this method. But if not, you can use this generic function instead:

```
const asyncQuery = (db, sql) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        db.query(sql, (err, results) =>
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(results)
        )
    );
```

Now you can put those `return` statements directly in your loop, and they will exit the `db.req` callback:

```
req.on("data", async data => {
  try {
    const fetchedData = JSON.parse(data.toString())
    for (const {id, invoiceNumber} of fetchedData) { // Simpler loop
      const results = await asyncQuery(db, `SELECT * FROM payments WHERE invoice_id = '${id}' and status = 1`)
      if (results.length > 0) {
        // Now we are in the req.on callback, so this will exit it:
        return res.json({
          status: "error",
          message: `Payment is already done for invoice number ${invoiceNumber} ! Please delete the payment first.`,
        });
      }
    }
    for (const {id} of fetchedData) {
      await asyncQuery(db, `UPDATE invoices SET status = 0 WHERE id = '${id}'`);
    }
    res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: "invoice deleted",
      deletedInvoices: fetchedData.map(({id}) => id)
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "something went wrong!",
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: the `return` statement applies to the scope of the function that it is in. And your loop is in an outer scope.

**Possible solution**

You could define another variable in the same scope as you `while` loop, check it in each iteration, and when you want an inner scope to end the loop, you not only return but also set that variable.

Something like:

```
// ...
let index=0
let shouldLoopContinue = true
while(shouldLoopContinue && index<fetchedData.length) {
// ...
```

and:

```
// ...
if (err) {
  resolve()
  shouldLoopContinue = false
  return res.json({
    status: "error",
    message: "something went wrong!",
  })
}
// ...
```

And also in any other place that returns and should stop the loop.

**Explanation**

In your case:

- the scope you call `return` from is the **callback** function passed as a parameter to `db.query(...)`.
- `db.query(...)` itself is in the scope of the **callback** function passed to `new Promise(...)`
- ... which is in the same scope as your `while` loop

So when you call `return` the way you do now, you only end the execution of that inner callback.